# CloudWatch Event trigger on HTTP requests

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have an EC2 instance that runs some very occasionally needed services. The application that uses the services will keep retrying until it finds the server so I was wondering if I can set up a CloudWatch Event Rule that will trigger a Lambda that starts my EC2 when HTTP traffic is directed at the EC2. Any ideas on whether this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, but its possible with **API Gateway** to accept HTTP request and trigger Lambda.
Inside the lambda code your can write logic to start EC2 using AWS SDK.

AWS Guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ec2-example-managing-instances.html

Example code : https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/ec2/src/main/java/com/example/ec2/StartStopInstance.java